# struct with char** val

Tags: c, pointers, stack

I am implementing a kind of bucket stack that uses the following struct as nodes

```
struct NodeBucket {
    char** val;
    struct NodeBucket* next;
};
```

The way it is supposed to work is that each bucket can hold a specified amount of values, when full a new NodeBucket is created and linked to the previous and then filled and so on.
I have ran into confusion when trying to add a second value to the first bucket. When I add the first value I create the first bucket, set the value to the input using `temp->value = &val`. Now I am unsure of how to add the rest of the inputs. I have tried using indexing (firstBucket->val[1] = val) but this doesnt seem to be the right way. I would appreciate any help. Yes this is homework, and I am a relative beginner to C, coming over from Python.

EDIT

```
void push(char* val, struct Stack *stack){
    if (isEmpty(stack)){
            struct NodeBucket *temp =malloc(sizeof(struct NodeBucket));
            temp ->val = &val;
            temp->next = NULL;
            stack->firstBucket=temp;
            stack->topElt++;
    }else if(!isEmpty(stack)&& size(stack)!=stack->bucketSize){
            stack->firstBucket->val[stack->topElt] = val;
            stack->topElt++;
    }
```

Comment: You need to show us some code and point out where it is broken/you are stuck

Comment: added my push function. Thanks!

Comment: `temp ->val = &val;` ?? Storing an address of a temporary variable is definitely not the thing to do.

Comment: What I am doing there is creating a bucket, storing the val in it and then attaching it to the stack. I could be wrong, but that part seems to be functioning well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The way it is supposed to work is that each bucket can hold a specified amount of values,

So your bucket has to have enough storage fo`stack->bucketSize` values, the values being strings and therefore of type `char*`. You are not doing this, in fact you are effectively creating a pointer to `char*` and assigning it the address on the stack of `val` which will go away when the function returns.

struct NodeBucket needs to know how many items it is storing.

```
struct NodeBucket {
    size_t numValues;
    struct NodeBucket* next;
    char** val;
};
```

Also you need to allocate space for the array of vals. Initialise it like this:

```
struct NodeBucket* temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
temp->val = malloc(sizeof(char*) * stack->bucketSize);
temp->numValues = 0;
temp->next = NULL;
```

Free everything up in reverse order.

Note that I put `val` at the end because you could then take advantage of the [flexible array member feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) to reduce the mallocs (and frees) to one.

Then to add a new string, you see if `numValues` is less than `stack->bucketSize`. If it is, you add the string to the end of the array (`stack->firstBucket->val[numValues] = val`) and increment `numValues`. If not, you create a new `NodeBucket` and add it there.

Comment: Thank you for a very clear answer. The initializing memory is definitely something I forgot. Now the nit picky part, my strut definition is only allowed to be in the way I originally posted, with only the two values in that order.  In my stack struct I do have an int topElt which is essentially the same as your numValues I believe